# Typescript: merging / overwriting nested interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have deeply nested objects like this (with more than 3 levels):

```js
{
    a1: 'foo1',
    b1: [
        {
            c2: 'foo2',
            d2: [
                {
                    e3: 'foo3',
                    f3: 'foo3'
                },
                {
                    e3: 'bar3',
                    f3: 'bar3'                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

and I've created nested interfaces like so:

```js
export interface Level3 {
    e3: string;
    f3: string;
}

export interface Level2 {
    c2: string;
    d2: Level3[];
}

export interface Level1 {
    a1: string;
    b1: Level2[];
}
```

I'm transforming the most deeply nested object to something else, while leaving everything the upper structure untouched. For example:

```js
export interface Level3Transformed {
    e3Transformed: number[];
    f3Transformed: number[];
}

export interface Level3 {
    e3: string;
    f3: string;
}
```

When I declare a `Level1Transformed` interface that is otherwise the same as `Level1`, but has `Level3Transformed` instead of `Level3`, is there any way to reuse all the in-between interfaces (like `Level2`)?

Or is there some other smart way to structure / declare similar nested objects like this while avoiding a lot of duplicate interfaces?

Edit: without using the OR operator?

Comment: Not sure but can we not try something like this: `interface level { [key: string]: string | Array<Level>}`? And to answer *is there any way to reuse*, yes. You are already exporting interfaces. Just import them and use as required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  export interface Level2 {
     c2: string;
     d2: Level3[] | Level3Transformed[];
 }
```

Or you could use generic types:

```
 export interface Level2<T> {
   c2: string;
   d2: T[];
 }

 export interface Level1<T> {
   a1: string;
   b1: Level2<T>[];
 }
```

And then either

```
  Level1<Level3>
```

or

```
 Level1<Level3Transformed>
```

Comment: I'd rather have duplicated interfaces than a not-that-useful interface with OR.
But the generic type is interesting! I can't think of a way to make this work with more than 3 levels though :(

Comment: Duh, brain fart! Awesome, thanks, TIL about generic types :)

Comment: @usagidon glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply give `OR operator` in `level2`

```
export interface Level2 {
    c2: string;
    d2: Level3[] | Level3Transformed[];
}
```

This way your `level1` type object will be `level3` or `level3transformed` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template types, e.g.:

```
export interface Level3<T> {
    e3: T;
    f3: T;
}

export interface Level2<T> {
    c2: string;
    d2: Level3<T>[];
}

export interface Level1<T> {
    a1: string;
    b1: Level2<T>[];
}
```

Then you can have `Level1<string>` or `Level1<number[]>`.

If you want to change even the names of properties in `Level3`, you can pass the whole `Level3` as a template type, down to `Level2`.

Note that you can also define a default value for `T`, e.g. `export interface Level1<T=string>`, then you can use just `Level1` for the string version, or `Level1<number[]>` for a modified version.